# WIX not installing components during upgrade

Tags: visual-studio, wix, windows-installer, wix3.5

I am new to Wix and StackOverflow. I had a wix installer (say version v1) with a few components (say component c1). There was a change in directory structure and hence I deleted the component c1 from the wix file, added c2 and created a new installer v2. The upgrade from v1 to v2 did not add/modify any files and the installer did not show any error message.
So, I added the component c1 back to the wix file (so the file contains both c1 and c2) and created a new installer v3.
v1 is able to upgrade to v3 but v2 to v3 does not add/modify any files.

I did not make any changes to the Feature, but from the logs (v2 to v3 upgrade) I noticed that the feature shows "Installed:Advertise" whereas the v1 to v3 upgrade showed it as "Installed:Local".
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you are doing a minor upgrade and have broken the component rules. Take a look at [Doing a small update or minor upgrade in MSI? Use MSIENFORCEUPGRADECOMPONENTRULES](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2007/1/4/doing-a-small-update-or-minor-upgrade-in-msi-use/).

Basically you should probably look into implementing a Major Upgrade.

Comment: Thanks Christopher. It worked after implementing a major upgrade.